# Retrieve field offset via recursive query in db2

Tags: sql, recursion, db2

Assume that I've got key-value table of `field_name`-`field_len` pair.

As follows:

```
-----------------------------------
field_name       |    field_len   |
-----------------------------------
FIELD_A          |    10          |
-----------------------------------
FIELD_B          |    20          |
-----------------------------------
...
-----------------------------------
FIELD_X          |    2           |
-----------------------------------
FIELD_Y          |    100         |
-----------------------------------
```

Then I need an offset of each field to be in third column. 
Like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
field_name       |    field_len   |      offset     |
-----------------------------------------------------
FIELD_A          |    10          |         0       |
-----------------------------------------------------
FIELD_B          |    20          |        10       |
-----------------------------------------------------
...
-----------------------------------------------------
FIELD_X          |    2           |       250       |
-----------------------------------------------------
FIELD_Y          |    100         |       252       |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

So I've wrote this script based on some manuals ([1](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/i-db2connectby/),[2](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/3618/Recursive-SQL-in-DB2-Converting-rows-to-columns.html)):

```
with offsets (column_name, length, offset) as
 ((select column_name, length, CAST(0 AS SMALLINT)
     from myschema.sizes a
     start with rrn(a) = 1)
  union all
  (select b.column_name, b.length, offset + o.length
  from offsets o, myschema.sizes b
    where rrn(b) between 2 and 100))
select * from offsets;
```

However, it keeps getting into infinite loop.

Also this version gives same result:

```
with offsets (column_name, length, offset) as
 ((select column_name, length, CAST(0 AS SMALLINT)
     from myschema.sizes a
     fetch first row only)
  union all
  (select b.column_name, b.length, offset + o.length
  from offsets o join myschema.sizes b on b.column_name = o.column_name
    where o.column_name <>'LAST_FIELD'))
select * from offsets;
```

I guess, that messed somewhere with exit condition, but can not figure exact place to fix it.

Would be great to avoid any table specific metadata like row count too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a recursive CTE for this.  Just a cumulative sum.  Something like this:

```
select s.*,
       (sum(field_len) over (order by rrn(s)) - field_len) as offset
from myschema.sizes s;
```

I'm not sure how the ordering is defined.  It seems to be based on a function `rrn()`.